# When using Microsoft's MVC, how do i enforce TLS/SSL bydirectional authentication for incoming requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl

I'm writing a rest based api, for use when communicating between servers, and implementing some portions of it in microsoft's mvc.

I'd like to make sure that incoming requests are:

- coming over https
- signed with a valid ssl certificate
- restricted to a known list of servers; ie. the certificate is issued to someone on my
  approved whitelist

What is/is there a pre-defined method or pattern for implementing this kind of system, in the Msoft MVC/IIS stack?

Comment: Did you actually look at the controller class - that your controllers inherit from? How did you manage to overlook the "Request" property?

Comment: do you have an example of how i might check a request against a store of acceptable certificates (or, preferably, a store of domain names, + a check for a valid certificate from an acceptable source - so i can be flexible enough to let the connection change its certs if it wants, as long as they're from reputable sources)

Answer (score 5):

> coming over https

You can either prevent IIS from serving port 80 (non-ssl) or use the [RequireHttpsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

> signed with a valid ssl certificate

When a browser visits a website, the browser does not use a certificate (99.99% of time).  If you want the request to include a certificate, it's referred to as a [client certificate](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication).

> restricted to a known list of servers; ie. the certificate is issued to someone on my approved whitelist

What is a *known list of servers*?  If this is an IP Address range, then you can use [IP Security](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity).  Otherwise your question is to vague.

Comment: requests are not coming in from a browser - they're coming in, programmatically, from another server. i'm not aware of servers instantiating browsers when they want to communicate with each other? i'd rather not limit access to a fixed list of ips - i'd rather, if possible, check that the domain name matches a list of known domain names, and that it is signing its request with a matching ssl cert

Comment: The question was confusing based on *incoming requests are: signed with a valid ssl certificate*.  Requests should *never* bed signed with SSL certs, so it was a confusing request.  You certainly could instantiate a browser to do requests, but I personally would never do it.

Comment: a client certificate is an ssl certificate - you linked to that in your answer?

Comment: Most definitely not (implementation).  An SSL Certificate - use X.509 certificates and hence asymmetric cryptography to *assure the counterparty* with whom they are communicating, **and** to *exchange a symmetric key* (for encrypted communications).  A client certificate only adds an additional layer of security, that is to say that only people with a certificate can communicate (this does not assure the counterparty as strongly as SSL, as many can have the same cert).  You can use a client certificate without SSL (and the reverse which is 99.99% of SSL traffic).

Comment: that's definitely not correct - while many ssl connections only have server side certs, and the vast majority of server side certs are stored in a X.509 format, that's just a subset of what the ssl standard definition covers. you can get an overview of the bydirectional authentication built into ssl in question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/how-does-bidirectional-authentication-using-ssl-work and you can read up on alternative certs here http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5081

Comment: Here's a post describing how this might be implemented with another, non microsoft/.net based stack: http://philipkershaw.blogspot.ca/2011/08/java-ssl-whitelisting-of-peer.html (it only speaks to "client" side whitelisting, but can easily adapted to run on the "server" - a better choice of vocabulary would be to call them "peers")

Comment: It's a problem of implementation.  You cannot just use any Client Certificate for SSL and have it work out of the box correctly.  I can use windows cert manager to create plenty of certs but using them on an IIS for SSL box will result in a failure in *assure the counterparty* in browsers of machines not on the domain the cert was created from.  This is why Certificate Authorities exist (to assure the counterparty).  However, the inverse is true.  You can use *any* SSL Cert (CA, Windows Cert Mgr, or Linux whatever) as an IIS Client Cert.

Comment: Yes, i'm asking an implementation specific question - does the microsoft's .net implement this portion of the spec, and, if it does, how do i use it? maybe the correct answer is "microsoft's .net only properly supports server side certificates, and doesn't provide functionality to properly check client side certificates against a certificate authority", possibly coupled with "the .net system assumes a client-server connection, and is not meant to be used for bidirectional authentication for server-server connections"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47062/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-blueberryfields)